# pandas' read_sql with a list of values for WHERE condition

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

Suppose a dataframe `scoreDF`:

```
          date       time      score
sec_code
1048      2015-02-25 09:21:00     28
2888      2015-02-25 09:21:00     25
945       2015-02-25 09:21:00     23
4         2015-02-25 09:21:00     22
669       2015-02-25 09:21:00     15
```

I need to make a MySQL query to retrieve all rows matching the values in `scoreDF.index` i.e. `sec_code` column.

Normally I'd go for a loop:

```
    finalResultDF = DataFrame()

    queryString = 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE sec_code = ' + code

    for code in scoreDF.index:
        queryResultDF = sql.read_sql(queryString, con)
        finalResultDF.append(queryResultDF)
```

Would it be possible to do this differently without a loop passing a list of values i.e. `scoreDF.index` as WHERE condition? I Googled for hours and some mentions 'parameter' to `read_sql` but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can actually do this without any loop.

```
queryString = 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE sec_code in '+tuple(scoreDF.index)
```

This will give the results directly.This is assuming `scoreDF.index` is a `list`.If it is already a `tuple` then no typecasting is required.

Comment: I needed str(tuple(scoreDF.index)) to avoid errors.  (Due to python 3, I think.)

Comment: I needed str(tuple(scoreDF.index)) as well and I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: You should use `params` parameter in read_sql to avoid sql injection

Comment: How to use it for 2 or more tuples ?

Comment: @Shashank join them to make a new tuple...using list or a new tuple..

Comment: Will not work if length of `scoreDF.index` is 1, `tuple(scoreDF.index)` will result in `(1048,)`, for example.

Answer (score 7):

As bolec_kolec suggested, I think best practice is to use `params` when calling read_sql. Here's how I generally do it (Python 3.7):

```
scoreIndex = scoreDF.index.tolist() 
queryString = 'SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE sec_code = ANY(%(scoreIndex)s)'

queryParams = {'scoreIndex': scoreIndex}
queryResultDF = sql.read_sql(sql = queryString, con, params = queryParams)
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works for SQL Server (where the marker is `?`) and avoids SQL injection. We fill the query string with as many `?` as needed. Then, we pass the list of values via `params`.

```py
queryString = """
  SELECT * FROM tableA
  WHERE sec_code in ({})
""".format(','.join(['?'] * len(scoreDF.index)))

queryResultDF = sql.read_sql(sql = queryString, con, params = scoreDF.index)
```