# I can't my query string to work with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am having trouble using `ConfigParser()` and an `ini` file with `pandas`.

I get this error:

```
UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy
```

I have this defined in my `ini` file:

```
[options]
myQuery = SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [Books].[dbo].[springBooks]
```

In my Python script, I assign it the `dbQuery` variable like this:

```
dbQuery = config['options']['myQuery']
```

And I use it like this:

```
mydb = pyodbc.connect(Driver=driver,
                      Server=server,
                      Database=db,
                      uid=user, pwd=pw) 

print(dbQuery)

df = pd.read_sql_query(
    dbQuery, mydb)
```

When I print the query out, it looks fine like this:

```
SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [Books].[dbo].[springBooks]
```

If I hard-code the query into the statement it works fine:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(
    '''SELECT TOP (1000) * FROM [Books].[dbo].[springBooks]''', mydb)
```

What could I be messing up so bad?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen [this related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082494/getting-a-warning-when-using-a-pyodbc-connection-object-with-pandas)?  And is it just the `UserWarning` that you're concerned about or is there a functional difference between the behavior when using `ConfigParser` parsed string versus your hardcoded string shown in the last block?

Comment: @jedwards thanks, from that related link, I changed from pd.read_sql_query to `sqlalchemy`.  I can print out the results of the `sqlalchemy` query to the screen, but how would I write it to a `dataframe` like I did with `read_sql_query`?  Thanks