# Hide pandas warning: SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I want to hide this warning `UserWarning: pandas only support SQLAlchemy connectable(engine/connection) ordatabase string URI or sqlite3 DBAPI2 connectionother DBAPI2 objects are not tested, please consider using SQLAlchemy` and I've tried

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)

import pandas
```

but the warning still shows.

My python script read data from databases. I'm using `pandas.read_sql` for SQL queries and `psycopg2` for db connections.

Also I'd like to know which line triggers the warning.

Comment: FutureWarning or UserWarning?

Comment: @JiříBaum The warning message is a UserWarning. I've tried to surpass both `FutureWarning` and `UserWarning`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried this and it doesn't work.

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Therefore, I used SQLAlchemy (as the warning message wants me to do so) to wrap the psycopg2 connection.

I followed the instruction here: [SQLAlchemy for psycopg2 documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/postgresql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.psycopg2)

A simple example:

```
import psycopg2
import sqlalchemy
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{user}:{pw}@{host}:{port}/{db}")

query = "select count(*) from my_table"

pd.read_sql(query, conn)
```

The warning doesn't get triggered anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Using the following worked well for me:

```
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore').
```

I am using pandas with pyodbc and was previously getting the same warning.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings that you're filtering right now are warnings of type `FutureWarning`. The warning that you're getting is of type `UserWarning`, so you should change the warning category to `UserWarning`. I hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71083448/8293793) answers your question regarding why pandas is giving that warning.

Comment: hi `UserWarning` doesn't work as well. I'll edit my question

Comment: Hm.. that's weird. I've tried an simple example also using psycopg2, and no warnings were printed when I've filtered the warning. Are you perhaps connecting to your database in another script?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same error when using psycopg2 to connect to a PostgreSQL database. I was able to successfully hide this warning with the follwing lines:

```
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)
```

I **think** they key here is that UserWarning needs to be a class and not a string like you have in your example.

Hopefully this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Its absolutely ok to ignore warnings if you get the job done. Don't forget to reset warnings.

```
import warnings

def your_function():
    warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=UserWarning)
    # YOUR pyodbc-Code goes here.
    warnings.simplefilter("always")  # Reset warnings.
```