# Is there a work around for Pandas 2.0 deprecation of pyodbc for obscure databases?

Tags: pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, read-sql

According to Gord Thompson here: [Getting a warning when using a pyodbc Connection object with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71082494/getting-a-warning-when-using-a-pyodbc-connection-object-with-pandas/71083448#71083448)
pyodbc is not deprecated and I agree, for databases with a SQLAlchemy dialect. But I am using an obsure database - Providex on which Sage 100 ERP is based. I can use pyodbc as in `cnxn = pyodbc.connect("DSN=SOTAMAS16",autocommit=True)` to access/read data with read_sql() in 1.4.47 or below, with warnings. I cannot and do not want to write data to the database with the ODBC interface. I also do not want to be relegated to using old releases of Pandas. I am not opposed to SQLAlchemy. Is there a way to use my ODBC DSN by perhaps, creating my own SQLAlchemy dialect using the PVXODBC ODBC Driver?

I can come close to being able to use SQLAlchemy with

```
sql3 = "SELECT ItemCode FROM CI_Item"
engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://user:pwd@SOTAMAS16?autocommit=True")
items= pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(sql3), con=engine.connect())
```

to which I get this error: "pyodbc.Error: ('37000', '[37000] [ProvideX][ODBC Driver]Expected lexical element not found: FROM (1015) (SQLExecDirectW)')"
which makes sense since the database is not Microsoft Sequel Server. This the closest dialect that I have found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't use `pyodbc` to execute the query and load results with `pd.DataFrame.from_records`. Something like:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc

cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=SOTAMAS16', autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT ItemCode FROM CI_Item')

cols = [c[0] for c in cursor.description]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=cols)
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien this works. I added one minor variation:    
 pd.DataFrame.from_records(cursor.fetchall(), columns=[col[0] for col in cursor.description])  This gets the column names for me.  It just seems a shame that if I want to upgrade to Pandas 2.0 I have to change all of my existing code to not use read_sql.

Comment: Thanks for this trick too :-)  I updated my answer related to your comments.

Comment: I added one additional line to my code `df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors="ignore")`  My database brings in some columns as decimal and pandas had difficulty doing math with them until I changed the type to float. This line of code changes the numeric columns for me.

Comment: I was trying to get oracledb to work with read_sql for hours through all types of strange workarounds.  This just works!!!