# Is there a way to make SQLAlchemy accept a list as a named parameter with the IN operator?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa

query = "SELECT * FROM students WHERE name IN :name"
t = as.text(query)
pd.read_sql(t, con=conn, params={'name': ['Ravi', 'Rami']}
```

This is what I tried but it results in a syntax error.
Is there a workaround to accept a list as a named parameter with the IN operator?

Comment: Have you tried suggestions here: [pandas-read-sql-with-where-clause-using-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53839451/pandas-read-sql-with-where-clause-using-in)

Comment: I think you need parentheses around `(:name}`

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo

t = as.text(query)

Should be

t = sa.text(query)

Comment: that's just because when I tried to retype the code I made the typo but it's not related to the problem I'm facing, I'll try the suggestions in the comments;