# use a column with the type list for pd.read_sql

Tags: python, sql, pandas, database, dataframe

Previously, from my table in the database, I sorted all the column headers and saved them in DataFrames so that I can use them later.

I try to apply each row from b (is a column in the database with multiple values) of column 0 (not bennant) in the case with the type list to the function pd.read_sql(). To get from each row a DataFrame of data from the database.

[image: 1]

```
5   ['temperature_ers_lite_3_wermser_0_elsys_0_t']
11  ['temperature_ers_lite_1_wermser_0_elsys_0_t']
17  ['temperature_ers_lite_15_wermser_0_elsys_0_t']
23  ['temperature_ers_lite_8_wermser_0_elsys_0_t']
29  ['temperature_ers_lite_2_wermser_0_elsys_0_t']
...
```

i also transform to type list

```
 b = a.tolist()
```

I have found several solutions but I could not apply them once with params which did not work and SELCET * FROM ... WHERE ... did not work with the list either.
I am stuck with the approach

```
 queryString = "SELECT * FROM Raummonitoring"
params = [b]
df = pd.read_sql(queryString, connection, params=params)
```

is it possible with a list like this to read with pandas ?
[pandas' read_sql with a list of values for WHERE condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28735213/pandas-read-sql-with-a-list-of-values-for-where-condition?answertab=votes#tab-top) with this approach it unfortunately does not work eithe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem as follows:

- I have read out the complete table
- filtered it as I needed it
- with a for-loop I went through the columns one by one and saved them in a list

> ```
> temp_df_utc_r = []
> for i in temp_utc_r:
>     x = i
>     intt = pd.DataFrame(temp_utc_r[f"{x}"])
>     intt = intt.dropna()
>     temp_df_utc_r.append(intt)
> ```

- from this list I can enter in the further since the a DataFrameist